# c#: make a 3rd party object serializable

Tags: c#, serialization

On my own object I can add the metatag [Serializable] to make it serializable. Now I use a 3rd party library that I need to be serializable. I inspected the code and it should not be a problem. Is there a way to fix this without altering the 3rd party code?

Comment: can't you just subclass?

Comment: this depends a lot on a: which serializer (is it `BinaryFormatter`?), and b: what the type looks like; personally, I'd just use a separate data model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My advice would be: serialize **data**, not **implementation**. The fact of the existence of a 3rd-party object is nothing to do with the data; that is an implementation detail. As such, I always offer the same advice: if serialization **ever** gets complex, the first thing to do is to introduce a separate DTO model that represents the **data** in isolation of the implementation, and just map the current state to that DTO. This allows you to handle implementation changes without impact on the storage, and allows otherwise non-serializable objects to be serialized.

Some serializers offer workarounds - for example with protobuf-net you can a: supply the serialization information for any type at runtime, and b: supply a "surrogate" to use automatically when it gets tricky, but - using a DTO model is simpler and easier to maintain.

Your use of `[Serializable]` suggests `BinaryFormatter`; in my opinion, this is **almost never** a good choice for any kind of storage, since `BinaryFormatter` relies on implementation details. It works nicely for passing data between two in-sync app-domains, though

Comment: The thing is that the object I need to serialize is already part of DTO objects and used by webcomponents provided (from mvc controls toolkit). Therefor I need to make it serializable.

Comment: @Patrick if you have something that isn't serializable in a DTO, then it isn't a DTO

Comment: The thing is that the mvc controlstoolkit gives a tracker object to track changes in a grid. For example this then would be a 
List<Tracker<MyObject>>>. I downloaded the source for the toolkit and added the serialization myself. Furthermore I asked the maintainer to add it to the toolkit and he will.

Answer (score 0):

If the types are public you should be able to use the `XmlSerializer` to do what you want.

There's [more information on this here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)

> Serializes and deserializes objects into and from XML documents. The
>   XmlSerializer enables you to control how objects are encoded into XML.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly take your subclass and make it serializable.

```
[Serializable] public class Foo: Bar {}
```

Comment: Don't forget the constructor if using XmlSerializer.

Comment: @Ingenu, what is special about the constructor?

Comment: @BuhBuh it needs to have a public parameterless constructor to be used by `XmlSerializer`; however, it should be noted that `[Serializable]` relates to `BinaryFormatter`, not `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: @BuhBuh XmlSerializer will fail if you don't have a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Write an adapter or be prepared to do something more extreme like disassembling the assembly, injecting the serializable attribute and reassembling.

Comment: O_o. That is a very extreme case. If you have your target class sealed, you don't have permission to create duplicating dto, cannot serialize it to Binary, XML, JSON or CSV and some other unbreakable force is hidering you to accomplish the serialization in code, only then digg in the assembly and do modifications in IL.